# textpipe / other replace regex method

Tags: regex, replace, sed, find, wildcard

I would like these lines of text:

```
[URL=http://something.com/attachment/ap0djrk27dja]flower.mpg - 129.7 MB[/URL]
[URL=http://something.com/attachment/XjotHS4jrgod]book.mpg - 200.3 MB[/URL]
[URL=http://something.com/attachment/as5r8ukAr64W]vacation.mpg - 2.1 GB[/URL]
[URL=http://something.com/attachment/kauirnmfaf57]love.avi - 30.4 MB[/URL]
```

converted into:

```
http://something.com/attachment/ap0djrk27dja/flower.mpg.html
http://something.com/attachment/XjotHS4jrgod/book.mpg.html
http://something.com/attachment/as5r8ukAr64W/vacation.mpg.html
http://something.com/attachment/kauirnmfaf57/love.avi.html
```

using Textpipe or other text manipulation tool.

I know how to do it in MS Word using the ff. wildcard find and replace methodology:

```
(Find what) \[URL=(*)\](*) - * *\[/URL\]^13
(Replace with) \1/\2.html^p
```

I know as well that Textpipe pro has a a "Find pattern (MS Word style)" replace filter and I have tried the above MS word wildcard find and replace method but it does not work and showing some error.

The reason I could not use MS word to do the task is that I have text files that I need to work with that contains hundreds of thousands of lines which MS Word could simply not handle as it would hang if you paste tremendous amount of text. I am open to methods besides using textpipe.

Answer (score 1):

using sed:

```
sed -n 's/[^=]*=\([^ ]*\).*/\1.html/;s/]/\//p' input_file
```

or more strict:

```
sed -n 's/^\[URL=\([^ ]*\).*/\1.html/;s/]/\//p' input_file
```

Comment: Thank you @perreal but the output was:
    http://something.com/attachment]kauirnmfaf57/love.avi
I need:
    http://something.com/attachment/kauirnmfaf57/love.avi.html

Comment: actually not working like a charm, i am getting duplicates. i used

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe" -i "s/[^=]*=\([^ ]*\).*/\1.html/;s/]/\//p" "C:\Users\Asus\Downloads\werk\input.txt"`

Comment: use `-n` flag when executing sed. or remove the `p` from the last part.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work in GNU sed. If `file` has the text:

```
sed -r 's#.*(http://[^]]*)\]([^ ]*).*#\1/\2#' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^\[URL=\([^]]*\)\]\([^ ]*\) .*/\1\/\2.html/' file
```